# Mechanism of photolysis of HX

Tags: photochemistry

What is the mechanism for the photolysis of $\ce{HX}$ to dihydrogen and dihalogen ? From the low quantum yield (0.3% for $\ce{HI}$ according to one paper) it seems unlikely to be a chain process but I am not sure why it would not be.

Comment: Can you reference the paper? I am absolutely uncertain about this, but my guess would be, that there are just not enough right pairings to form dihalogen and dihydrogen.

Comment: the question is pretty much based on an incorrect premise as it turns out the actual quantum yield is closer to one - I was incorrectly reading the quantum yield for triodide formation. I've found a mechanism here: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=o24m1CLMR4cC&pg=PA253#v=onepage&q&f=false