# Mechanism for the decomposition of HI

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides

I've been trying to find the mechanism for the gas phase decomposition of hydrogen iodide:

$$\ce{ 2 HI (g) <=> H2 (g) + I2 (g)} $$

Anyone know of sources where I can get information on this? I found a 1927 paper in PNAS but wondered if there is anything more recent. This is the 1927 paper:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1085202/

Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A. 1927 Oct; 13(10): 720–726.
The Photochemical Decomposition of Hydrogen-Iodide; the Mode of Optical Dissociation

Comment: Could you give us a link to that original 1927 paper?

Comment: This is a 2006 paper-http://www.cder.dz/A2H2/Medias/Download/Proc%20PDF/posters/%5BGII%5D%20Production%20from%20electrolysis%20&%20thermochemical%20cycles/336.pdf

Comment: Related:http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31225/mechanism-of-photolysis-of-hx

Comment: Are we talking about non-catalytic decomposition?

Comment: Yes, non-catalytic.